# Different Cross-Validation Techniques Yielding Identical Evaluation Metrics

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I implement three ML algorithms (K-Nearest Neighbor, Decision Trees, and Random Forest) and use four different cross-validation techniques (Hold-Out Method, Leave-One-Out Method, K-Fold Cross-Validation, Stratified K-Fold Cross-Validation) for each algorithm. The goal is to evaluate performance metrics and compare the techniques and algorithms. My code runs, but the evaluation metric values for different techniques are the same. Is it normal for these values to be identical, or might I be doing something wrong?

Here's part of my code:

```py
# Initialize classifiers
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, metric='minkowski', p=2)
dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20, criterion='entropy', random_state=0)

classifiers = {'KNN': knn, 'Decision Tree': dtree, 'Random Forest': rf}

# Define cross-validation methods
loo = LeaveOneOut()
kf = KFold(10)
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)

cv_methods = {'Hold-Out Method': (X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test),
              'Leave-One-Out Method': loo,
              'K-Fold Cross-Validation': kf,
              'Stratified K-Fold Cross-Validation': skf}

# Perform classification and evaluation for each classifier and cross-validation method
for clf_name, clf in classifiers.items():
    print(f"Classifier: {clf_name}")
    for cv_name, cv_method in cv_methods.items():
        if cv_name == 'Hold-Out Method':
            X_train_cv, X_test_cv, y_train_cv, y_test_cv = cv_method
            clf.fit(X_train_cv, y_train_cv)
            y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_cv)
        else:
            scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=cv_method, scoring='accuracy')
            

        # Calculate evaluation metrics
        accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test_cv, y_pred)
        precision = precision_score(y_test_cv, y_pred, average='weighted')
        recall = recall_score(y_test_cv, y_pred, average='weighted')
        f1 = f1_score(y_test_cv, y_pred, average='weighted')
        confusion = confusion_matrix(y_test_cv, y_pred)
```

And here are the outputs, which are identical for each classifier and cross-validation method:

```py
Classifier: KNN
Hold-Out Method Metrics for KNN:
Accuracy: 0.864620939
Precision: 0.8661
Recall: 0.8646
F1 Score: 0.8652
Confusion Matrix:
[[326  41]
 [ 34 153]]

Leave-One-Out Method Metrics for KNN:
Accuracy: 0.864620939
Precision: 0.8661
Recall: 0.8646
F1 Score: 0.8652
Confusion Matrix:
[[326  41]
 [ 34 153]]

K-Fold Cross-Validation Metrics for KNN:
Accuracy: 0.864620939
Precision: 0.8661
Recall: 0.8646
F1 Score: 0.8652
Confusion Matrix:
[[326  41]
 [ 34 153]]

Stratified K-Fold Cross-Validation Metrics for KNN:
Accuracy: 0.864620939
Precision: 0.8661
Recall: 0.8646
F1 Score: 0.8652
Confusion Matrix:
[[326  41]
 [ 34 153]]

Classifier: Decision Tree
Hold-Out Method Metrics for Decision Tree:
Accuracy: 0.980144404
Precision: 0.9801
Recall: 0.9801
F1 Score: 0.9801
Confusion Matrix:
[[363   4]
 [  7 180]]

Leave-One-Out Method Metrics for Decision Tree:
Accuracy: 0.980144404
Precision: 0.9801
Recall: 0.9801
F1 Score: 0.9801
Confusion Matrix:
[[363   4]
 [  7 180]]

K-Fold Cross-Validation Metrics for Decision Tree:
Accuracy: 0.980144404
Precision: 0.9801
Recall: 0.9801
F1 Score: 0.9801
Confusion Matrix:
[[363   4]
 [  7 180]]

Stratified K-Fold Cross-Validation Metrics for Decision Tree:
Accuracy: 0.980144404
Precision: 0.9801
Recall: 0.9801
F1 Score: 0.9801
Confusion Matrix:
[[363   4]
 [  7 180]]

Classifier: Random Forest
Hold-Out Method Metrics for Random Forest:
Accuracy: 0.981949458
Precision: 0.9820
Recall: 0.9819
F1 Score: 0.9819
Confusion Matrix:
[[364   3]
 [  7 180]]

Leave-One-Out Method Metrics for Random Forest:
Accuracy: 0.981949458
Precision: 0.9820
Recall: 0.9819
F1 Score: 0.9819
Confusion Matrix:
[[364   3]
 [  7 180]]

K-Fold Cross-Validation Metrics for Random Forest:
Accuracy: 0.981949458
Precision: 0.9820
Recall: 0.9819
F1 Score: 0.9819
Confusion Matrix:
[[364   3]
 [  7 180]]

Stratified K-Fold Cross-Validation Metrics for Random Forest:
Accuracy: 0.981949458
Precision: 0.9820
Recall: 0.9819
F1 Score: 0.9819
Confusion Matrix:
[[364   3]
 [  7 180]]
```

Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 1):

The line

`scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=cv_method, scoring='accuracy')`

Does not modify the `clf` object such that it is fitted. (I've made this mistake myself a few times. It is a bit misleading because you see the model fitting  in the console.)

What is happening now is that the model is fitted in this section

```
if cv_name == 'Hold-Out Method':
            X_train_cv, X_test_cv, y_train_cv, y_test_cv = cv_method
            clf.fit(X_train_cv, y_train_cv)
            y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_cv)
```

And you are using this model 4 times to evaluate.

To test this, remove "Hold-Out Method" from `cv_methods` and you will probably get an error that the model is not fitted yet.